# Login View Controller over modal View Controller

Tags: ios, authentication, modal-dialog, uisplitviewcontroller

**The following scenario:**

My iPad app has a SplitViewController as it's main VC. After starting the app (new or from background) I have a fullscreen login view that (obviously) disappears after entering the correct password.

**The problem:**

After login, I want to present the exact same screen that was there BEFORE moving to background. This works fine UNLESS there is a modal view on top of the split view (like settings etc).

**What I tried:**

In AppDelegate I store my self.window.rootViewController, make the login vc as my root vc and after login I set my stored root VC as actual root VC. But then the (modal) settings view is not visible and can not be opened again *(Warning: Attempt to present VC on SplitVC which is already presenting VC)*. In fact, no other modal view can ever be opened (unless app is properly closed).

Second try: Instead of setting the login VC as root VC I presented it as a fullscreen modal view on top of my split view. This yielded the same error message as the first try but a different result. After entering background mode the login VC won't be presented at all (since there already was a modal view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was the following:

Create a property that can store my modally presented VCs (they are all embedded in a UINavigationController)

```
@property (nonatomic) UINavigationController *navController;
```

When creating the login vc I store my modal vc (which may be `nil` which is fine), dismiss it and present the login vc

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
LoginViewController *loginViewController =  [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginView"];

self.navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController;
if (self.navController) {
    [self.navController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:loginViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

And when the login is successfull I dismiss the login vc and restore the modal vc (if available)

```
if (self.navController) {
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:self.navController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is b'coz you R trying to present the VC while it is actually loaded as RootViewController .

Try using this :

> UISplitViewController :
>
> - Once loaded the Root and as well as MasterViewControlller , You will make the UIViewControllers as SubViews for Your
>     RootViewController.. From the UIViewController , If you want to revert
>     back to the RootViewController , Try this :

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

I just thought your problem is similar.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am not trying to present any vc that is currently root vc. I edited my question since it seems to be confusing (See the part *second try*). Also, where should I put that line?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this way.

Root VC is main screen not login page.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Inside the above code, present your login page to your root VC.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{
    //Use below method or similar method to remove any presented VC on Root VC
    if ([((UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController).visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[RLSplashViewController class]]) {
            NSLog(@"AppDelegate dismiss splash page");
            [self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
        }
    //And present your login VC
}
```

Inside the above code, First and very import, remove any VC that presented on the root VC. And then present login page to your root VC.

I am currently using this way to present splash page(from background or new), in your case, it is login page. Hopes this is helpful for your case : )

Comment: Thanks, I followed a similar approach now